Google calendar invitation preview is always in Greenwich Mean Time
I am using google's calendar api to create and send invitations to a google calendar meeting. For some reason, only in Outlook, the preview and the subject show the event dates in Greenwich Mean Time. The calendar does display it correctly.
my implementation is exactly like Google's documentation as explained here https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert

Take a look at the raw invitation MIME source (you can do that if you send it to a Gmail mailbox) and compare it to what Outlook itself sends
